# Mysql: Union two columns with count

Tags: mysql, count, union

I'm looking for a sql statement for the following problem:
Here is an excerpt from my table

```
'from_city' 'to_city'
New York    Boston
Chicago     New York
New York    Los Angeles
Dallas      San Francisco
Miami       New York
Dallas      Los Angeles
```

The expected result should look like this:

```
City              Count   Percentage
New York            4        33%
Los Angeles         2        17%
Dallas              2        17%
San Francisco       1         8%
Miami               1         8%
Chicago             1         8%
Boston              1         8%
```

So I need to union the two columns 'from_city' and 'to_city' which I was able to with:

```
(SELECT from_city AS City FROM table) UNION
(SELECT to_city AS City FROM table)
```

But now I don't know how to appy the count and percentage on the result set. 
Can you please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use subquery:

```
SELECT
  city,
  COUNT(1) AS c,
  CONCAT(100*COUNT(1)/sums.total, '%') AS p
FROM
  (SELECT  from_city AS city FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_city FROM t) AS cities
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 
     COUNT(from_city)
    +COUNT(to_city) AS total
  FROM t) AS sums
GROUP BY
  city
ORDER BY 
  c DESC
```

-note, that double count won't work in common case (thus used sum of counts by both columns) Check the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fed985/7).

Also you've not specified format of percentage - i.e. how many signs should be in it (because it may be non-integer) - so I've left it as it is

Comment: Well, because of [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e063b/1) as a sample. With `2 * count(*)` we'll get wrong percentage

Comment: Why would there be null values in the table?

Comment: Because _"in common case"_

Comment: Seems more like a special case where the table allows null values.

Comment: Not sure I got you. For me, "common case" = set of all possible "special cases" (including "general case"). Thus I've treated `2 * COUNT(*)` as a possible fail on some cases

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City, COUNT(*) AS Count, ROUND(100*COUNT(*)/total) AS Percentage
FROM (SELECT from_city AS City
      FROM table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT to_city AS City
      FROM table
     ) AS u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 * COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM table) AS t
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0f00/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    cities.City,
    COUNT(*) as `Count`,
    CONCAT((COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*)*2 FROM table)) * 100, '%') as Percentage
FROM (
    SELECT from_city AS City FROM table UNION ALL
    SELECT to_city AS City FROM table
) as cities
GROUP BY cities.City
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following query will provide your desired results

```
SELECT 
  city, 
  count(*), 
  count(*)/(SELECT count(*)*2 FROM table)
FROM
  (SELECT from_city AS city FROM table
    union all
  SELECT to_city AS city FROM table) a
GROUP BY 
  city
```

Comment: You have to use `UNION ALL`. By default it's `UNION DISTINCT`, so duplicates will be removed.

Comment: Oh snap! Barmar is correct, answer has been modified